# pycharm "no declaration to go to"

Tags: pycharm, declaration

I'm quite new to python and pycharm.
I created a project under folder `c:\runpython`, and write my main code under that folder. I also define one function `ABC` in `c:\test\defabc.py`.

I also add `c:\test\` to sys.path and run `from defabc import ABC`.
I can run ABC successfully in my project, but when hovering over `ABC` function (or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) in my code, it shows "cannot find declaration to go to". Can someone let me know how can I check the function declaration quickly? Do I need to set some path for pycharm? thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Do File-> Invalidate Caches/restart..

Reboot if necessary.

Startup Pycharm and wait for a while (it took a couple of minutes). This worked for me.